# Assigning headers in text files and building arrays

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, header

I am writing a program that reads a text file and parses the information inside it. An example of the text file is as follows:

```
->DQB1*02:02:01:01
GAACTTTGCTCTTTTCACCAAAACTTAAGGCTCCTCAGGGTGTGTCTAAGACAACAGCAGTAAAAATGTCTATGACAGCAATTTTCTCTCCCCTGAAATATGATCCCCACTTAATTTGCCCTATTGAAAGAATCCCAAGTATAAGAACAACTGGTTTTTAATCAATATTACAAAGATGTTTACTGTTGAATCGCATTTTTCTTTGGCTTCTTAAAATCCCTTAGGCATTCAATCTTCAGCTCTTCCATAAT

->OMIXON_CONSENSUS_M-86-11-9517_DQB1*02:02:01
GTCCAAGCTGTGTTGACTACCACTACTTTTCCCTTCGTCTCAATTATGTCTTGGAAGAAGGCTTTGCGGATCCCTGGAGGCCTTCGGGTAGCAACTGTGACCTTGATGCTGGCGATGCTGAGCACCCCGGTGGCTGAGGGCAGAGACTCTCCCGGTAAGTGCAGGGCCACTGCTCTCCAGAGCCGCCACTCTGGGAACAGGCTCTCCTTGGGCTGGGGT

->GENDX_CONSENSUS_M-86-11-9517_DQB1*02:02:01:01
TGCCAGGTACATCAGATCCATCAGGTCCAAGCTGTGTTGACTACCACTACTTTTCCCTTCGTCTCAATTATGTCTTGGAAGAAGGCTTTGCGGATCCCTGGAGGCCTTCGGGTAGCAACTGTGACCTTGATGCTGGCGATGCTGAGCACCCCGGTGGCTGAGGGCAGAGACTCTCCCGGTAAGTGCAGGGCCACTGCTCTCCAGAGCCGCCACTCTGGGA
```

I am trying to assign all the lines starting with `>` as a header so I can create a header array and the remaining text as a sequence array so afterwards I can align the sequences and parse. I am having trouble with assigning the headers. So far in my code I have as follows:

```
def readfile():

with open ("testAllele1.txt", "r") as myfile:
    y = myfile.read()
with open(y) as z:
    for line in z: # build array
        counter=1
        if line.startswith(">"): #header array
            header(counter)=line
            counter=counter+1
        else:
            sequence(counter)=line #sequence array
```

Please help! (Also I am like a beginner to intermediate programmer so nothing too difficult please)

Answer (score 1):

Your example is broken.
All lines start with `->`

So I assume that you want to split them at the first space character.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

# read the file and split into lines
y = open("testAllele1.txt", "r").read()
z = y.splitlines()

# initialize
header = []
sequence = []

#loop over all lines
for line in z:
    if line.startswith("->"):
        h, s = line.split()
        h = h[2:] # cut away the leading "->"
        header.append(h)
        sequence.append(s)

print header
print sequence
```